# Cypress - how to get element by last word in it

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

If this is the ID -> div id="random_is_good"

I want to get this element but only to catch "_is_good"

how can i do it ?

Or I only have the start and end -> "random_ _good"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol * - Match elements that with partial text match

```js
cy.get('[div*="_is_good"]')
```

Symbol ^ - Match elements that starts with given value

```js
cy.get('div[id^="random_"]')
```

Symbol $ - Match elements that ends with given value

```js
cy.get('div[id$="_good"]')
```

Comment: oh, so just put the start over there and it is done? :D Can I place the star elsewhere if I want to get it by start, or it doesn't matter...

Comment: `*` will check for partial text. So you can use any partial text from `random_is_good` like eg. `random_` or `_good` or `_is_` or `random_is` etc.